# Кнопка вызова функции python flask

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, jinja2

Как с помощью библиотеки jinja2 при нажатии кнопки можно вызвать функцию в python, передав параметр id этой кнопки? Долго просматривал документацию и искал похожие вопросы, но так и не нашел ничего схожего.

Имеется следующие части кода:

**main.py**

```
def json_load(num):
with open('db/pub_keys.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file_dumps = json.load(file)
    for elem in file_dumps:
        if elem.get('id') == num:
            print(f'\nPK user with num {num}:')
            print(elem.get('meta').get('pub_key'))
```

**file.html**

```
<button type="button" id=1 onclick="" class="btn btn-dark">Иванов Д.Е.</button>
```

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку вызывалась функция json_load() с передачей в ней аргумента id нажатой кнопки. пытался использовать {{ }} внутри onclick и action, но это не помогло.

Возможно ли реализовать это по средствам jinja2?

Comment: подумайте, какие части  выполняются на сервере и какие на клиенте. Как вы обычно во flask код на сервере выполняете? Что нужно сделать на клиенте, чтобы запрос на сервер послать?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Jinja2** – это всего лишь библиотека для упрощения генерации **HTML** страниц. А нужная Вам задача решается средствами простых **HTTP** запросов, которые можно сделать как с помощью чистого **HTML**, так и с помощью более гибкого **JavaScript**'a. В любом случае для передачи данных на сервер нужен обработчик запросов на северной стороне.

---

#### 1.1. Чистый HTML + скрытые параметры

Решая задачу чистым HTML'ем страница будет перезагружаться. На странице нужно сделать такие формы:

```html
<form action="/process_data/" method="POST">
    <!-- скрытый параметр -->
    <input type="hidden" name="index" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Нажать 1">
</form>

<form action="/process_data/" method="POST">
    <!-- скрытый параметр -->
    <input type="hidden" name="index" value="2">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Нажать 2">
</form>
```

А на серваке ловить эти действия и параметры:

```py
@app.route('/process_data/', methods=['POST'])
def doit():
    index = request.form['index']
    # ... обработать данные ...
```

---

#### 1.2. Чистый HTML + параметры в адресе

Фласк позволяет легко обрабатывать аргументы как часть пути:

```html
<!-- аргумент как часть пути -->
<form action="/process_data/1/" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Нажать 1">
</form>

<!-- аргумент как часть пути -->
<form action="/process_data/2/" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Нажать 2">
</form>
```

А на серваке так:

```py
@app.route('/process_data/<index>/', methods=['POST'])
def doit(index):
    # ... обработать данные ...
```

---

#### 1.3. Чистый HTML + JSON форма

Форме можно поставить тип формата, тогда поддерживающие этот JSON браузеры отправят данные в нужном формате, а не поддерживающие вернутся к классическому `form url encoded`:

```html
<form action="/process_data/" enctype="application/json" method="POST">
    <!-- скрытый параметр -->
    <input type="hidden" name="index" value="1">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Нажать 1">
</form>

<form action="/process_data/" enctype="application/json" method="POST">
    <!-- скрытый параметр -->
    <input type="hidden" name="index" value="2">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Нажать 2">
</form>
```

<sub>Больше подробностей и реально интересных примеров с формой JSON доступны внизу по ссылке №5.</sub>

На сервере ловить JSON тоже достаточно легко:

```py
@app.route('/process_data/', methods=['POST'])
def doit():
    data = request.get_json(silent=True)
    index = data["index"]
    # ... обработать данные ...
```

---

#### 2. HTML + JavaScript

Очевидно, что способы выше предполагают много повторяющегося HTML кода, что явно не удобно, особенно если захочется что-то поменять. JavaScript может значительно упростить код предоставив большую гибкость, а также позволит не перезагружать страницу при отправке данных:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="process(1);">Нажать 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="process(2);">Нажать 2</button>
```

Теперь конкретный формат запроса будет определён лишь в одном месте. В самом скрипте можно поступить по-разному.

<sub>Для простоты здесь используется JS в связке с библиотекой jQuery.</sub>

**2.1.** Вариант для сервера из **1.1**, где данные передаём HTTP аргументами:

```js
function process(index) {
    $.post("/process_data/", {'index': index}, function (data, status) {
        alert(`Data: ${data}\nStatus: ${status}`);
    });
}
```

**2.2.** Вариант для сервера из **1.2**, где данные передаём как часть пути:

```js
function process(index) {
    $.post(`/process_data/${index}/`, {}, function (data, status) {
        alert(`Data: ${data}\nStatus: ${status}`);
    });
}
```

**2.3.** И наконец, вариант для сервера из **1.3**, c JSON на борту:

```js
function process(index) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/process_data/",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {"index": index},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    });
}
```

Этот вариант, передача данных через JSON, можно легко комбинировать с предыдущим, где что-то передаётся через путь URI. И зачастую в разработке это бывает полезно – например, для создания и редактирования некой сущности на сайте (вроде аккаунта, страницы или товара) числовой или slug идентификатор указывается как часть пути, а описание/контент отправляется в теле запроса.

Стоит отметить, что на этом возможности HTTP только начинаются: есть разные типы методов (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, и т.д), которые тоже несут в себе важную смысловую нагрузку для сервера, есть куки/cookies, заголовки/headers, статусные коды HTTP, которые также помогают передавать информацию между клиентом и сервером. Но это всё материалы для дальнейшего изучения `:)`

---

#### Полезные и использованные материалы

1. [Документация Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) (в которой, вообще-то, есть всё необходимое)
2. [jQuery AJAX get and post](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)
3. [Пример AJAX с JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8517361/5308802)
4. [Про использование JSON во Flask'e](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20001229/5308802)
5. [Отправка JSON формы чистым HTML](https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, Вы мне очень помогли!

Comment: @АлександрСоколов благодарность на этом сайте выражают стрелкой вверх и галочкой принятого ответа `;)`

Comment: не стоит утверждать, что нельзя передать json данные через обычную html форму (обработку слегка поправить для конкретного типа). Можно любые данные с помощью обычного http запроса отправить. Основное отличие от javascript варианта в том, что без javascript у вас страница перегружается, а с javascript вы можете http-запросы без смены страницы в браузере делать.

Comment: @jfs я догадывался об этом! Добавил в ответ, спасибо.

Comment: я не имел в виду, что enctype можно заменить. Вы можете со стандартным enctype отправить -- это проблемы сервера  интерпретировать присланный текст как json документ -- опять таки: вы можете всё что угодно послать с помощью обычной формы (это не значит, что enctype  меняется -- что имеет смысл только если у вас `<input type="file">`). Представьте у вас написано в поле: `{"a":  [{"b": 1}, {"b": 1}]}` по умолчанию по проводам это уйдёт как: `%7B%22a%22%3A+%5B%7B%22b%22%3A+1%7D%2C+%7B%22b%22%3A+1%7D%5D%7D`. Для вашего кода это прозрачно `requests.form['name']` вернёт json текст

Comment: Спасибо за идеи. Лайк