# Получение переменной из js в python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-3.x, flask

У меня есть выпадающий список, выбранные элементы которого записываются в переменную, которую я вывожу в консоль. Такой вопрос:

**Как реализовать получение переменной(`selectedItem.value`) из `js` во `flask python`?**

`app.py:`

```
description = ['one','two','three','four','five','six']

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        docs = request.form.getlist('sel')
        return render_template('login.html', description=description)
    return render_template('login.html', description=description)
```

`login.html`

```
<select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" onchange="printValue(this)">
   {% for desc in description %}
      <option value="{{desc}}">{{desc}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
<p id="mySelectedValue" style="margin-top: 10px;"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function printValue(selectedItem){
       $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value);
       console.log(selectedItem.value);
    }


function process(index) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/login/",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        data: {"selectedItem.value": selectedItem.value}
    });
}


</script>
```

Полный код [тут](https://repl.it/repls/ElectricStrongDecimal#main.py)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Кнопка вызова функции python flask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811924/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-python-flask) – посмотрите в ответе раздел 2.3, там показана передача данных из JS в Python.

Comment: @AivanF., спасибо. т.е только с помощью ajax можно передать? я просто не понимаю как это в моем случае реализовать

Comment: да, точнее с помощью HTTP запросов, это (не считая WebSockets) единственный способ связи браузерной страницы и серверного кода. Данные можно и в большинстве случаев нужно передавать в формате JSON, для этого сформируйте JS объект с нужными серверу данными и кидайте через AJAX по URI пути, который будет обрабатываться сервером должным образом. А извлекать значения из `<select>` можно легко с помощью jQuery.

Comment: @AivanF., обновил с использованием `AJAX`. Можете посмотреть?

Comment: Что я говорил про обработчик?) На браузере отправляется запрос по адресу `/login/`, но в серверном коде нет соответствующего `@app.route`. В общем, сейчас сделаю работающую версию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Клиентская часть:

```html
<select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker sel" multiple data-live-search="true" onchange="optionClick(this)">
    {% for descr in description%}
        <option id="val" value="{{descr}}">{{ descr }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<!-- Данные можно отправлять по кнопке -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="process();">
    Process
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function printValue(selectedItem) {
    $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value);
    console.log(selectedItem.value);
}
function process(selectedItem) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "selectedItems": $('#sel').val()
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
}
function optionClick(selectedItem) {
    printValue(selectedItem);
    // Или можно отправлять в любой другой момент
    // process();
}
</script>
```

Серверная часть:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

description = ['one','two','three','four','five','six']

# Браузер обращается по пути "/", но с методом GET
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        docs = request.form.getlist('sel')
        return render_template('login.html', description=description)
    return render_template('login.html', description=description)

# Из скрипта мы обращаемся по тому же пути, но методом POST
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def login_post():
    data = request.json
    print('Got data:', data)
    return jsonify({
        'status': 'SUCCESS',
        'data': data,
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! отметил как верный. У меня буквальн один вопрос. у меня там кнопка по ссылке в коде, которая открывает модальное окно и котором значение переменной.

Comment: как можно сделать так чтобы когда на `process` нажимаешь это окно модальное открывалось?

Comment: я добавил в него классы нужные из другой кнопки, но не работает

Comment: @abby Просто вызывайте код открытия этого окна в функции `process` или внутри функции по `success`, если нужно использовать ответ сервера. Если ваш вопрос о том, как в принципе отображать модальные окна, то задавайте полноценный новый вопрос, т.к отдельная большая тема, не для комментов. Либо посмотрите и используйте простые примеры модальных окон: [Bootstrap3](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp), [Bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/),

Comment: дело в том, что у меня есть работающее модальное окно, просто связано с другой кнопкой. в `process` функции прописал `document.getElementById('#exampleModalCenter')`, но он не ловит его что-то, поэтому не открывает