# Flask. Как при нажатии на кнопку отправить ajax-запрос?

Tags: ajax, flask, sqlalchemy

У меня есть база данных sqlite3:

```
class Family(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'family'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    with_plants = db.relationship('Genus', backref='f')


class Genus(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'genus'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    with_plants = db.relationship('Plants', backref='g')
    family_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('family.id'))


class Plants(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'plants'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    genus_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('genus.id'))
```

**Как, при нажатии на кнопку, отобразить выборку из БД в текстовом поле  textAreaField на форме?**

В sqlalchemy эта выборка выглядит следующим образом:

```
variable = Genus.query.filter(Genus.family_id.like(1))
```

То есть: отобразить все рода растений (genus), у семейств (family) которых id = 1.
Если не получится сделать такую выборку, то помогите сделать любую другую выборку из этой БД.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1074721/234134

Comment: интересует как отобразить именно базу данных

Comment: Вернуть результат запроса на страницу, ничем не отличается от отображения значения из словаря/списка и.т.п.

Comment: В этом ответе описано, как по клику обращаться к серверу – [Кнопка вызова функции python flask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/811997/198251). Дальше остаётся передать ответ из БД в JSON на фронт, и там просто отобразить.